# Calling a function gives result only if it has a cout statement in the beginning

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to implement a simple stack in C++. My code is working fine except this function minm(). I'm getting very unexpected result. If I comment out the line in bold then my procedure doesn't even run. Also, you can see that the only difference between my functions minm() & minmm() is of the bold line. Please help me out.

The explanation is as follows:

Functions minm() & minmm() under consideration are in *italic* & this line **cout<<"called"<< endl;** is in **bold**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE = 100000000;

class MyStack{
    int *a;
    int *min, *max;
    int top;
    int size;

    public:
        MyStack(int s=MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE);
        void push(int i);
        int pop();
        int maxm();

        int minm()  // This function is failing
        {
            //cout<<"called\t";
            if(!stackEmpty())
            {
                cout<<min[top]<<" = " <<a[min[top]]<<endl;
                return a[min[top]];
            }
            return NULL;
        }

        int minmm()   // This function is working
        {
            cout<<"called\t";
            if(!stackEmpty())
            {
                cout<<min[top]<<" = " <<a[min[top]]<<endl;
                return a[min[top]];
            }
            return NULL;
        }

        bool stackEmpty();
        void printStack();
};

int main()
{
    MyStack s;
    int t;

    while(true)
    {
        scanf("%d",&t);
        s.push(t);
        cout<<"min = "<<s.minm()<<endl;
        cout<<"min = "<<s.minmm()<<endl;

        if(t==-1) break;

    }
}
```

Input:

```
234
23
-1
```

Output:

```
min = 0
called  a[0] = 234
min = 234

min = 0
called  a[1] = 23
min = 23

min = 0
called  a[2] = -1
min = -1
```

Now, I'm getting same (wrong) result from both functions on [ideone](http://ideone.com/uXmXOj) while function minmm() returns on my system (I use GNU GCC compiler in Code::Blocks 12.11).

Comment: Are you sure your pointers are pointing to valid memory?

Comment: Including the constructor and `stackEmpty` would be helpful.

Comment: And `push()` as well.

Comment: @chris Yeah that one too...can I have my cape and tights back now? ;)

Comment: Yes, I haven't pasted the complete code just for the sake of clarity. The function minmm() is same as the other function minm() except that cout line & minmm() is returning correct result.

Comment: Should I add the complete code? :o

Comment: Your outputs doesn't seem to be linked with your code: for example, where's the "max" text? and why after "called" there isn't a newline (endl)?
Italic and bold are not working within code...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I made a few changes but I forgot to update them here.

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/hjYnoV)'s my code & I'm getting runtime error on ideone while it works fine on my laptop (I'm using GNU GCC Compiler in Code::Blocks 12.11).

Comment: Have you considered stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Now, [this](http://ideone.com/uXmXOj) is weird. I was getting correct result from my function minmm() on my system while ideone shows the result from both functions (that should be the case anyway). But please help me in figuring out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I haven't done that before or rather I don't know how to. So.. No. :/

Comment: Seems that the ideone problem was the too big array size.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. Thanks. :)
But still not getting the correct result.

Comment: It is generally expected that you have tried debugging the problem yourself before coming to SO. Or do you intend to ask SO every time you encounter a problem?

Comment: Am I alone in being slightly exasperated when a question can only be answered by looking at code on a different web site?  And when you look at the code on the web site, you find that what you've got in the question on SO bears only a passing resemblance to the actual code (for instance, the code on ideone is a template class)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stackEmpty, your are not returning false:

```
bool stackEmpty(){
    if(top == -1) return true;
    return false;
}
```

or

```
bool stackEmpty(){
    return (top == -1);
}
```

Comment: Oh No! I can't believe I did that. :'(
Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: It works fine even on [ideone](http://ideone.com/YPP2Wi) now. ;)
Thanks a lot. :)